# structure for applying Identity on a multi-project solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, multi-project

I've been working on a Web API solution that's separated on various projects, one of each is the API itself which contains the controllers and Views but all the Business Logic is done in all the other projects (being one of them responsible for all database iteration).

Now I want to apply Authentication using Identity which I wasn't familiar with but was able to understand a lot better thanks to [this series of articles](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) and so was able to get it to work on a test solution.

My question here is, how should I organize the different parts of the Identity implementation? Should I...

- Make everything directly on the API project?
- Create a separate project for all the Identity Implementation except for the controllers?
- Use it some other way that you will suggest?

*If you suggest using different project, will I be able to pass the owin context between the projects? how?

Comment: Tell us more about what you want to get done? Your project structure will depend on what you need to do.

Comment: @trailmax I want to be able to authenticate my users using a dynamic connection string. And trough their roles decide which modules (projects) of my solution they have access to.